# Do we have an MIDL RPC code generator for Java?

Tags: java, c, rpc, midl

I am working on a legacy code that is written C. The application is a client-server application built using the X/Open RPC specification using IDL's to generate client/server stubs (similar to a MIDL compiler). I am looking for a method/tool to generate Java client/server stubs by using the existing IDL files. Appreciate it if you can share your thoughts/experience in generating java stubs from (MIDL or X/Open RPC IDL).